# Creating a data frame in R with ifelse omits rows (vector values)

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, vector

Creating a dataframe out of a vector works well, like this:

```
VEC <- c("Vienna", "Tokyo")
TEST <- data.frame(
   "city" = VEC
)
# TEST now has 1 column ("city") with two rows ("Vienna", "Tokyo")
```

However, using `ifelse()` leads to the omission of all rows (vector values) other than the first one:

```
TEST <- data.frame(
   "city" = ifelse(is.null(VEC), NA, VEC)
)
# TEST now has 1 column ("city") with ONLY ONE ROW ("Vienna")
```

Is there any other way to check whether a vector is null while retaining the whole vector for the dataframe?

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized. and it's output should be of the same length as the condition `is.null(VEC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either

```
ifelse(is.null(VEC), NA, list(VEC))[[1]]
```

or

```
if (is.null(VEC)) NA else VEC
```